# Best Place To Populate ViewModels For Partials?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

Currently I am using a ViewModelFactory hanging off HtmlHelper in an extension method:

```
public static IViewModelFactory ViewModels(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
   var factory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IViewModelFactory>();
   return factory;
}
```

And then an example view with partial:

```
@model WidgetViewModel

<fieldset>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Form.cshtml", Html.ViewModels().EventForm() )
    }
</fieldset>
```

Is this a bad idea? It feels dirty. If so, where/how is the testable best practice to populate/build ViewModels for my Partials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally breaks the pattern.

ViewModels should be supplied via the controller, not the view.

Comment: WidgetViewModel is supplied via the controller. I need a populated EventForm model for my **partial** contained in the view.

Comment: Then put it inside WidgetViewModel.

Comment: That makes sense, but `WidgetViewModel.EventForm` would only be used in one situation. Where `WidgetViewModel` is used in several views. Create a third ViewModel ex `WidgetViewModelWithEventForm` just for this instance?

Comment: You have a choice.  Completely break and disregard the MVC pattern or make a new class.  I'd always make the new class.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my original instinct. ...bad and dirty lol